# Vlookup on closed file

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

needing some help with vlookup.

I need the code to open a workbook in the same directory as the active workbook and get x data next to a cell value in the column A then close the opened workbook.

Should've posted my try:
I need this code but looking on another workbook

```
value_m = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(date_m, Sheet1.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```

Comment: "I already done this before" then please try again and post your code when you're stuck somewhere..

Comment: If this is in a cell-formula, then you can use External References and skip the VBA entirely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Sheet1.Range("A:B")` specify another workbook.

```
Dim OtherWb As Workbook
Set OtherWb = Workbooks("MyOtherWorkbook.xlsm") 'workbook already open
```

and use

```
OtherWb.Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("A:B") 'instead of Sheet1.Range("A:B")
```

alternatively if the workbook is not open already

```
Set OtherWb = Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & Filename
```

or when in the same path

```
Set OtherWb = Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Filename
```

---

Note: to make it work on both (Windows and MacOS) you need to change `"\"` into `Application.PathSeparator` because Windows uses backslash `"\"` but MacOS slash `"/"` for path separating.